# Как вызвать вложенный объект в массиве JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Суть скрипта в том, что есть массив объектов (данных), которые прогоняются через цикл и выводятся уже на саму страницу. При попытке создания вложенного объекта попытка вызывать объект не увенчалась успехом, может, я что-то неправильно понимаю?
Нужно вывести текст, который внутри desc.inv на страницу

```js
const CATALOG = [{
    name: 'Категория 1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Категория 2',
  },
  {
    name: 'Категория 3',
  },
  {
    name: 'Категория 4',
    desc: {
      inv: 'подкатегория 4.1',
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Категория 5',
    desc: {
      inv: 'подкатегория 5.1',
    }

  },
];
// вывод
class Output {

  render() {
    let htmlCatalog = '';
    CATALOG.forEach(({
      name,
      desc
    }) => {
      htmlCatalog += `
                <li>
                    <span>
                        ${name}
                        <p>
                            ${desc.inv}
                        </p>
                    </span>
                </li>
            `;
    });
    const html = `
            <ul>
                ${htmlCatalog}
            </ul>
        `;

    ROOT_Wrapper.innerHTML = html;
  }

}
const outputPage = new Output();
outputPage.render();
// блок, в который нужно выводить
const ROOT_Wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: "Не увенчалась успехом" --- как много в звуке этом таится

Comment: А если так `${desc?.inv}`?

Comment: спасибо Вам большое!!!

Comment: Во первых вы работаете с `const`, к ним нужно обращаться ТОЛЬКО после объяления. `ROOT_Wrapper` не будет виден в классе, если я правильно понимаю, потому что вы его инициализируте и создаёте его экземпляр до объявления `ROOT_Wrapper`. Во вторых не во всех объектах массива `CATALOG` есть `desc.inv`, потому вам надо писать `desc?.inv || ''`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!